Disclosure of delivery fees in advertisement
If a product is only available for purchase online, and an ad for the product (e.g. on YouTube) displays its price, it is my understanding that under the Australian Consumer Law, the total price must include any delivery fees.
However, if the delivery fees vary from state-to-state, how do you handle displaying the product price in the ad if the same ad is shown to people in all different states? Is it sufficient to display the price excluding the delivery fee and include a disclaimer stating e.g. "+ delivery fees (vary depending on location)"?

You must display the minimum price that any customer can get the product for
So, in your case, you display the price inclusive of the cheapest delivery option and clearly state what the price includes and that delivery to other locations will be more expensive. For example:

$199.99 delivered by Australia Post to Sydney metropolitan area. Other delivery options and destinations attract additional fees.


Thanks! What about if the product was available in-store at retailers as well (let's assume the price there is identical to online minus the delivery fees) - would that lower price just be displayed on the ad instead?

@pigeonburger if that’s the lowest price, yes.
